# After first printf it does nothing (successful compile)

Tags: c, scanf, lag

When I run this code it doesnt even reach the while loop. It lags on `scanf`. Any ideas why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int hex_num;
    int mask=9;
    int test_int=0;
    int i=0;
    int res_mask;

    printf("Enter input as a hexadmcal number");
    scanf( "%x", &hex_num);

    res_mask= mask & hex_num;


    while( (res_mask!=mask) || i<32){
        hex_num=hex_num>>1;
        res_mask= mask & hex_num;
        i++;
    }

        if(res_mask==mask){
            test_int=1;
        }


    (test_int=1) ? (printf("yes")) : (printf("no"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without a \n at the end of your prompt, it will stay in the buffer and won't be displayed

Comment: Have you verified this with a debugger, or just because you aren't seeing anything get printed?

Comment: `(test_int=1)` --> `(test_int==1)`

Comment: Add something like `printf("hex_num = 0x%x\n", hex_num);` after the `scanf`; you'll see that that's not where it's hanging.

Comment: As for `while( (res_mask!=mask) || i<32)` it runs even when `i` > 32. Any ideas?

Comment: if it does, then `res_mask == mask`

Comment: @Felk I don't know why you think that; it isn't true ... mask is 9 but res_mask will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting to the while loop, which won't terminate because the `i<32` condition makes it continue until hex_num == 0, which makes res_mask == 0, which is != mask.

You need to fix the logic of your while loop (I would help with that but I don't know what you're trying to do) and you also need to either terminate your printf with a newline or call fflush(stdout) to flush the output. (Other possibilities are to print to stderr instead of stdout, since the former is unbuffered, or to call setbuf or setvbuf.)

Also, (test_int=1) sets test_int to 1 and is always true; better is

```
printf("%s\n", test_int ? "yes" : "no");
```

Update: Here is a program prints "yes" if the number entered contains the bit sequence 1001 and "no" if it doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int mask = 9;
    unsigned int hex_num;

    for (;;)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter input as a hexadecimal number: ");
        int nscanned = scanf("%x", &hex_num);
        if (nscanned == 1)
            break;
        else if (nscanned == EOF)
            return 0;
    }

    while (hex_num && (~hex_num & mask))
        hex_num >>= 1;

    printf("%s\n", hex_num ? "yes" : "no");

    return 0;
}
```

And here's another way to do it:

```
    for (;; hex_num >>= 1)
        if (hex_num < mask)
        {
            printf("no");
            return 0;
        }
        else if ((~hex_num & mask) == 0)
        {
            printf("yes");
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: When *i = 33, 34, ..* it checks the `while` condition, but ignores the value of `i` and continues iterating. How can other variables affect the `i` and `while`'s checking for a condition?
(debugger in Code::Blocks)

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy I don't understand your question. I explained -- clearly I think -- why the loop will continue indefinitely. After looping 32 times (on a system with 32-bit ints), hex_num will be zero (if it was initially >= 0 and < 2**31).

Comment: That's it? At the first time `(i<32)` makes while-loop iterating but while it does, the `(res_mask!=mask)` begins returning TRUE because `res_mask` = 0 and `mask` = 9.

So in any case while-loop has at least one TRUE, so it continues iterating.

Comment: I want to find if there is 1001 in the bit sequence of the hexaemical number so the loop can stop in its first appearence